# Paypal Not working on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am working a codeigniter project on localhost and In which I am using paypal sandbox payment method for payment.

In which I am facing a problem, The return url is not redirect automatically and also when I click on return merchant button then It is not returning any parameter to my url.

I have set all setting of paypal, I have set the auto return on from paypal account and also set the return url but still i am not getting any response.I am usging this form and parameters.

```
$paypal_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PHPGang Payment">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://112.196.5.114/psychics/component/images/logo.png">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://112.196.5.114/psychics/dashboard/profile/return_url">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://112.196.5.114/psychics/dashboard/profile/cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://112.196.5.114/psychics/dashboard/profile/return_url">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Add Funds</button>
</form>
```

I did not get where is my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, just add below line in your code, clear your browser's cache-cookies and try again:

< input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>

**NOTE 1:** After adding above code, PayPal will return response in POST method.

**NOTE 2:** Recheck and confirm that auto return must be enable from your PayPal business verified account.

You can check response by adding below line in your return page within PHP tag:

print_r($_REQUEST); OR print_r($_POST);

For more help about PayPal button parameters: [check documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have followed you step and after completion of payment It is not redirect to my return url automatically. The auto return is on but It is not working for autoreturn.

Comment: When I have clicked on return to merchant then it is redirecting on return url and showing me all transaction parameter. but I want to redirect it automatically so I can save all records of transactions. Thanks

Comment: And also the payment status is coming pending.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Could you please send me your sandbox email account, So that I can check with your account.
For my business account, it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Now it is working properly.